# Unable to sendcoins using bitgo express apis

Tags: transactions, api, testnet, sending, bitgo

Trying to access API URL: https://test.bitgo.com/api/v2/tbtc/wallet/walletid38u5348t9yj958jtv985j89g5/sendcoins

But every time getting same response:

```
{
    "error": "You have called a BitGo Express endpoint but this is the BitGo server. Please have a look at the BitGo Express documentation: https://www.bitgo.com/api/v2/#bitgo-express-rest-api",
    "name": "ApiError",
    "requestId": "irfo34r5541k06grtyy4j6n33",
    "context": {}
}
```

Is there any correction in API route? Or how can I successfully send coins using this api?

Comment: I don't understand why this is flagged as "customer relation with a company". Nothing in this question requires information only BitGo could have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sendcoins` is an endpoint that is only available on BitGo Express. BitGo Express is a proxy that runs on your own infrastructure, typically on port 3080.

Instead of calling `test.bitgo.com`, if you're running BitGo Express locally, try calling `localhost:3080`.

Comment: does that mean APIs will be accessible if we are running BitGo Express locally? Right now I am not running it locally.

Comment: Yes, it's a proxy that forwards requests to the API, but performs cryptographic operations client-side.